# Set emacs to NOT ask for password for encrypted file upon saving

Tags: org-mode, encryption

If I open an (symmetric, only a password is required) encrypted org mode file, by entering the password when the file opens, upon saving the file, emacs prompts me for the password.

I would much rather have emacs NOT ask me for the password upon saving the file, and remember the password that was entered when the file was opened, for the file password when the file is saved.

Is this possible?

Thanks ahead of time......

Comment: After posting my question I found https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12212/how-to-type-the-password-of-a-gpg-file-only-when-opening-it?rq=1     which I believe will answer my question. When I have time I will process this and answer my question....

Comment: Maybe, maybe not: one answer uses asymmetric encryption, the other turns on the password cache - from what I gather in previous interactions, you've nixed both of those approaches.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will dig into things and report back.